# Programmatically exclude ID of component to update (render/execute)

Tags: jsf, jsf-2.2

having some problems with developing custom components in JSF. I am building a component which wraps some javascript generated charts (javascript appends SVG elements to specified div). They have some animations by the time they render. When some part of chart is changed, there is made modification for only part of the chart by calling some .js scripts (whole chart is not rendered again). So, the rendered component looks some like this:

```
<div> <--- master container
    <span id="clientId" />
    <script> .js script for chart generation </script>
    <div id="chart">
         <svg>...</svg> <--- generated by script
    </div>
</div>
```

When is ajax render invoked with ID of this component, there is only `span` updated (so chart won't rerender). I catch the call, generate some modification script and return them to the client. Everything is ok.

The problem: when is updated some other component or container which holds this component with chart, the div `"chart"` is rerendered. Is there any server side way, how to exclude component to be updated?

Thanks